# What does this ID in CSS-Code?

Tags: html, css

Help me, please, to understand, what does the first line mean in CSS-Code:

```
#content-right h1 {
  font-size: 100%;
 .....
  c...
}
```

That's ID, right? Why is h1 after #ID, shouldn't it be like h1#ID?

Answer (score 9):

This is a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

It selects all `h1`s *inside of* `#content`

Answer (score 1):

`#content-right h1` means a H1 element inside an element with id "content-right".

`h1#content-right` means a H1 element with the id "content-right".

Answer (score 0):

basically it says all the `h1` inside of a container with the id `content-right`  have font-size 100% and whatever else is in there.

Answer (score 0):

above css works on **h1** inside div which have **id=content-right**

```
<h1>outside div</h1>
<div id ="content-right">
<h1>Inside div</h1>
</div>
```